# Compiling Haskell on Mac, for 64-bit Windows

Tags: windows, macos, haskell, cross-compiling, ghc

Is it possible to compile Haskell code on my Macbook, but for use on 64-bit Windows? I'm using GHC.

Thanks!

Comment: This is called cross-compilation. [It can be done](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Building/CrossCompiling), but you'd probably need to build your own GHC with custom settings. It's usually not worth it.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Thanks for the quick response. So you mean it is easier to compile the code directly on windows?

Comment: Cross compilation is usually not worth it for major platforms because you need to test the code on the target platform anyway. It's mostly useful for things like embedded systems where you can't run the compiler on the target itself.

Comment: Not an direct answer, but there is a [series of blog posts](https://medium.com/@zw3rk) on cross compiling Haskell.